# Usually,we transform image to base64 when it less than 8KB.But why the default value is 8?

Tags: node.js, web, gulp, webpack

Related to the bandwidth? But it's different in different place. So how to get a better value in different environment?

Comment: A better value of what? Better in what respect? What are you talking about? Where have you read about that 8KB limit? What’s stopping you from converting an image with a greater size to Base64?

Comment: the default is 8 because you made it 8, it seems

Comment: sorry,I mean when I use webpack(or orther tools) to bundle a project,and use a loader such as url-loader to inline small images as data URL into HTML or css.I know it used to transforming some small images. But I don't what's the better limit value for me,and how to comfirm the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more context.

My guess is that you are inlining small images as data URL into HTML pages. If the images are large, that would be quite detrimental (images loaded as separate resources will be cached for example).

Comment: sorry,I mean when I use webpack(or orther tools) to bundle a project,and use a loader such as url-loader to inline small images as data URL into HTML or css.I know it used to transforming some small images. But I don't what's the better limit value for me,and how to comfirm the value?